# What's the logic behind the "new block formatting context" solution to the "I want to these floats to be wrapped by their parent" pattern?

Tags: html, css

I've been having a really hard time figuring out exactly what a Block Formatting Context is.

I've read the CSS specs but it just doesn't make sense to me.

So if given this classic problem

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.container div {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>Sibling</div>
    <div>Sibling</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've learned to solve it by creating a new Block Formatting Context within       `.container`. This way, the `.container` div will expand and wrap the siblings floated elements.

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container div {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>Sibling</div>
    <div>Sibling</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**My understanding would be the following :**

The root element of my html document (here `<body>`) creates a root block formatting context.

All subsequent positionned boxes participate in this root block formatting context (given they are not floated or absolutely positionned) and are hereby positionned accordingly to the Block Formatting Context Rules.

This is the normal flow positioning.

Adding `float:left` to my siblings elements get them out of the normal flow and act accordingly to other rules defined in the float property section of the specs.

Then, adding `overflow:hidden` to my `.container` div creates a new block formatting context that wraps the float. Because when a block box establishes a new Block Formatting Context it becomes the reference to which the children are positioned.

**Now, this is my question :**

Why are the float gotten out of the root block formatting context but are wrapped in my `.container` block formatting context? Why aren't they out of the flow entirely?

What's the difference between the root block formatting context and the new block formatting context established by the `.container` div?

Comment: `Why Aren't they out of the flow entirely?` to be more exact, float aren't entirely out of the flow ... they remain part of the flow. ... [specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of **its container**, allowing text and inline elements to wrap around it. The element is removed from the normal flow of the web page, **though still remaining a part of the flow** ] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Comment: Okay, I think i get the difference. But why, then, are floats not wrapped in their parent if the parent doesn't establish a new block formatting context?

Comment: well, i would say because this the behavior of float .. and creating a new block formating context is a way to fix the float BUT it's totaly different from clearing ... float remain always float but inside the new formating block .. you may read this https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/

Answer (score 2):

> The phrase "a box's containing block" means "the containing block in which the box lives," not the one it generates. [Visual Formatting Model <sup>w3.org</sup>](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block)

In other words, the floated divs shown have a containing block of the `.container` div element, and inside of that block, they have been removed from the normal flow.

The next part is a little trickier, and I am not sure *why* this was done, but here is *what* was done. Although a div without a width definition can never overflow (it's width will always be 100% of its content width), using `overflow:hidden` when there is a float involved has some silent implications.

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. - [Floats <sup>w3.org</sup>](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats)

The result of the "must not overlap" rule here is that the containing box will have to have its height adjusted in an edge case of a "block-level, non-replaced element in the normal flow".

> In addition, if the element has any floating descendants whose bottom margin edge is below the element's bottom content edge, then the height is increased to include those edges. Only floats that participate in this block formatting context are taken into account, e.g., floats inside absolutely positioned descendants or other floats are not. - ['Auto' heights for block formatting context roots <sup>w3.org</sup>](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#root-height)

Based on that, the height of the `.container` div is extended to cover the floated nested div elements and exhibits the difference you are seeing.